# Need guidance on dynamic plotting using AChartEngine

Tags: android, achartengine, android-bluetooth

I am really new to java and I need help in dynamically plotting a graph on the same activity. I am using BLuetooth to receive data from my Arduino. I modified the BLuetoothChat sample code to suit mine. The only thing I need to know is how I can extract values from my String array and plot it on the graph dynamically. I took some ideas off a tutorial on using AChartEngine till I'm left with theses codes:

In LineGraph.java

```
package com.example.fypapp;

import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
import org.achartengine.GraphicalView;
import org.achartengine.chart.PointStyle;
import org.achartengine.model.Point;
import org.achartengine.model.TimeSeries;
import org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYSeriesRenderer;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;

public class LineGraph {

private GraphicalView view;

private TimeSeries dataset = new TimeSeries("Force Sensor Reading");
private XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

private XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer(); //used for customizing
private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public LineGraph()
{
    //add single dataset to multiple dataset
    mDataset.addSeries(dataset);

    //Customization for line 1
    renderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    renderer.setFillPoints(false);

    //enable customization
    mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    mRenderer.setChartTitle("Force Sensor Readings From Device");
    float textSize = 30, textSmaller = 20, angle = 270;
    mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(textSize);
    mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(true, false); 
    //mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
    mRenderer.setXTitle("Time (s)");
    mRenderer.setYTitle("Grip force (kgf)");
    mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(textSize);
    mRenderer.setYLabelsAngle(angle);
    mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(textSize);
    mRenderer.setChartValuesTextSize(textSize);
    mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(textSmaller);
    mRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.rgb(112, 128, 144)); //slate grey color
    mRenderer.setAxesColor(Color.YELLOW);
    mRenderer.setGridColor(Color.YELLOW);
    mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);
    mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);


    //adjusting margin width of y-axis (so y axis labels can be seen)
    int[] i = mRenderer.getMargins();
    i[0] += 50;//top
    i[1] += 50;//left (increment here)
    //i[2] = 0;//bottom
    //i[3] = 0;//right   
    mRenderer.setMargins(i);


    //add single renderer to multiple renderer
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
}

public GraphicalView getView(Context context)
{
    view = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(context, mDataset, mRenderer);
    return view;
}

public void addNewPoints(com.example.fypapp.Point p)
{
    dataset.add(p.getX(), p.getY());
}
}
```

In Point.java (class for the addNewPoints function in LineGraph.java)

```
package com.example.fypapp;

public class Point {

private int x;
private int y;

public Point( int x, int y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public int getX()
{
    return x;
}

public int getY()
{
    return y;
}
}
```

Honestly I'm not very sure why the point class is needed or how to use it.

In my main class, there is a case named MESSAGE_READ in a handler that is called when the Bluetooth connection is established. The codes in MESSAGE_READ case will keep on looping since it is continuously called from a run() in another class:

```
case MESSAGE_READ:

            readMessage = (String) msg.obj;

            if(readMessage != null)
            {

                Log.i(TAG, "Data sent is " + readMessage);

                    lineGraphPlot(readMessage); //a function I want to implement that plots the graph
            }
            count++;
            break;
```

readMessage is a public static String, with updated numerical data from the Arduino when MESSAGE_READ is called.

May I know how I can write a function called lineGraphPlot that will dynamically display the readMessage value on the graph from LineGraph? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do u want to show messages ? You can add a textview and dynamically update the test values .

Comment: May i know how that can be done? Thanks

Comment: You can add a textview above the graph layout and change text message.And if you want to do it on graph just use annotation text, it is available on graph.

Comment: to change text message is by using .setText() right? I'll take a look thanks!

Comment: Also have a look on series.addAnnotation("Text Message", 4, 200); it will appear on graph

Comment: Thanks it more or less solved my problem! Also, is there a way to make the graph appear/disappear? i dont mean only the graph itself, but the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

you have to see sample code of achartengine you will get all the info from it
http://www.achartengine.org/content/goodies.html

Comment: sorry I accidentally pressed enter earlier, my actual question is a bit more specific